# In Botium speech processing, MaryTTS api gives response as a binary data. How do i convert and get it as a Audio?

Tags: botium-box

I am a Beginner with the Botium speech processing. I am trying to convert the text to speech convertion and is using MaryTTs configured under botium speech processing. I configured Docker and from SwaggerUI i can see the response for TTS is a binary data. PLease find the screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPK0q.png)

How can I process this data and convert it into audio in Java? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from Botium Speech Processing is a byte array pre-encoded as WAV. You can write this 1:1 to a file named *audio.wav*.

Comment: Thanks Florian, i have some doubts though. What did you mean by 1:1? Should I be converting the byte array to wav string and then write it to a file named audio.wav? Thanks for helping once again

Comment: Its already binary data, no string conversion, just write the bytes to a file

Comment: you are welcome. would it be an option for you to share a Java code sample that I could add to the Botium Speech repository as starting point for other Java devs ?